# Creating pixel art / animation with flash

Tags: 2d, flash, animation

I have a friend that was the one creating graphics for my games. He left the town for some months (work, *sigh*) and I have tried to get in contact with him but it is impossible right now. Last talk I had with him he explained me that the graphics (2D) he did for my games were all made with flash and also the animations.

I can see why my pal does everything in flash: we develope for several movile platforms with different resolutions and having everything in vector format is nice.

My question is: How is he doing pixel art with flash? I recall he told me he was doing everything with vectors and later exporting to bitmpap, but, is it possible to do this with flash? Can't see how to do the pixel art feeling with vectors. If anyone could help here I would be really greateful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pixel-art and bitmap-graphics isn't exactly the same. A bitmap (or raster-graphic) doesn't imply anything about the "style" of the image. It's just a bunch of pixels... Exporting from flash (or any vector drawing application) to a bitmap is certainly possible.

Pixel-art on the other hand is a graphical style, usually with a limited palette and also often hand-painted (pixel per pixel). Naturally a piece of pixel-art is stored as a bitmap. Creating pixel-art with a vector-drawing application is counter-intuitive really. Pixel-art is made for a specific amount of available pixels. Scaling these graphics will result in blurry a picture, so there's no benefit in having them as vector-graphics.

A good vector-graphics artist has quite a different skillset from a good pixel-artist. It's not a simple matter of "export as bitmap".

Comment: I agree with you and I was a bit shocked when he told me he was doing everything in flash. The problem is that I don't know the workflow people using flash follows for this. This is why I was asking for someone with experience with it to let me digest my pal information. But I'm pretty sure he told me he was doing all the work inside flash.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that your friend is referring to Flash's ability to render out the screen as bitmap data. Sometimes this technique can be used to reduce processing footprint that your app uses, while still technically using vector graphics and working within the Flash IDE.

Comment: It seems this is what he is doing